# How do I set the time out for page load?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, windows-10, selenium-firefoxdriver

In the middle of download using selenium, I'm getting this error:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:57557/session/4aa4c28a-083-4477-b10d-1b35eff42b/url
>   timed out after 60 seconds.

I've tried to set the timeouts I've found:

```
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(myOptions));
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
```

but neither seems to affect ths 60s timeout. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, firefoxOptions,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40));
```

Comment: The first one didn't change anything, I get the same error. The second one, how can I combine that with `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()`? Can I do that?

Comment: Sorry @Jack, my previous second solution will not fit your case (I edited the answer), you can overload while instantiating the driver and give it a command timeout as a third parameter. I guess it will fix the issue please try it and let me know if it didn't work

Comment: The second one, with TimeSpan paramter, worked like a charm! Thanks! I'll mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Great ! , I left only the working solution to avoid conflict.